# "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module."

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, compiler-errors, winrt-xaml, executionengineexception

I'm writing an app in metro (XAML + C#) and I have fatal error which source I can't find:

```
System.ExecutionEngineException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module.
```

It came when I push the button and open new frame.

Weird is this that when I run this app on my laptop there is no any error but when i run it on another computer it have this fatal error when i going from one site to another.

Can someone help me? Anyone have some idea what can be wrong?

Comment: @HansPassant : reporting a bug will only help if it is a VS11/metro bug. But the message is vague enough that it can be a lot of other things, like a hidden dependency to a component installed on the laptop and not on other computers...

Comment: Or it could just be a plain WinRT projection bug.  We'll likely never will know from this question, the OP isn't updating it.

Comment: I am seeing this error on another application....a windows phone app on Windows 10.  Never occurred before.

The exception detail is just this....

    System.ExecutionEngineException was unhandled
    Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module.

There is no stack trace, no line number, no location, nothing else - just a dialog box with 'click here to copy error detail to clipboard'.  The MSDN site gives nothing except that it is an internal execution error.